# Matching combinations of values between four columns R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two df's of different lengths, with two columns in each that look something like this like this:

```
t<-c(1,3,4,2,6)
f<-c(3,4,5,6,8)
df1<- cbind(t,f)


t<-c(6,4,5,1,2,3,5,7,8,9)
f<-c(4,5,6,3,8,5,6,3,2,1)
df2<- cbind(t,f)
```

My question, is how can I add a new column to df1 which gives a 1 for matched values (in either combination of values, so 5-3 & 3-5) between both cols in df1 and df2, and a 0 if the values do not match.

I have tried case_when (which isn't correct), but might explain what I am trying to ask here (although I am aware that this would need to be run with both combinations of $t & $f)

```
df1$b <- case_when(df1$t & df1$f == df2$t & df2$f ~ '1') %>%
replace_na(0)
```

I hope that makes sense.

Jamie

Comment: Does the `1` case appear in your example? Is the expected result in the example `c(0,0,0,0,0)`? In one case the example is not particularly wisely chosen, in the other I do not understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes, 1-3 should appear in both df1 and df2 so should be a 1 in df$b

Comment: Ok, so this is not about matching rows but whether a certain combination appears in any row.

Comment: Yes that's correct - it's about matching combinations of values across set sets of multiple rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
df1$b <- paste(df1$t,df1$f) %in% paste(df2$t,df2$f) | 
         paste(df1$f,df1$t) %in% paste(df2$t,df2$f)
```

The `|` symbol means logical "OR", the `%in%` checks if each element of the first element is in the set of the second element.

Comment: @jogo postet something very similar only about a minute earlier. He added a delimiter between `t` and `f` which is favourable, if numbers can grow >9.

Comment: @Javi_VM The example data in the question are matrices (not dataframes).

Comment: @Bernhard `paste()` uses a delimiter (`sep=" "`)

Comment: Great, then also +1

Answer (score 3):

You can do with base R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  t=c(1,3,4,2,6),
  f=c(3,4,5,6,8))

df2 <- data.frame( 
  t=c(6,4,5,1,2,3,5,7,8,9),
  f=c(4,5,6,3,8,5,6,3,2,1))

df1$tf <- with(df1, paste0(t, '#', f))
df1$ft <- with(df1, paste0(f, '#', t))

df1$b <- with(df1, tf %in% paste0(df2$t, '#', df2$f) | ft %in% paste0(df2$t, '#', df2$f))
# > df1
#   t f  tf  ft  test
# 1 1 3 1#3 3#1  TRUE
# 2 3 4 3#4 4#3 FALSE
# 3 4 5 4#5 5#4  TRUE
# 4 2 6 2#6 6#2 FALSE
# 5 6 8 6#8 8#6 FALSE
```

or for short:

```
df1$b <- with(df1, paste0(t, '#', f) %in% paste0(df2$t, '#', df2$f) | 
                paste0(f, '#', t) %in% paste0(df2$t, '#', df2$f))
```

or

```
df2tf <- with(df2, paste0(t, '#', f)
df1$b <- with(df1, paste0(t, '#', f) %in% df2tf | paste0(f, '#', t) %in% df2tf)
```

Comment: should not `df2$t`and `df2$f`change their order on both sides of the `|`?

Comment: no, if you want to change the order for df2, then you need only one of the both combinations from df1.